# Next client component Syntax error, but i can't find it

Tags: reactjs, typescript, debugging, syntax, console

this is the error that appears on the frontend:

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Here there is the page.tsx component:

```
"use client"
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import { notFound, useRouter } from 'next/navigation'

interface Props {
    searchParams:{token: string, userId: string}
}

export default function Verify(props: Props) {
   const {token, userId} = props.searchParams
   const router = useRouter()

    useEffect(()=>{
        fetch('/api/users/verify', {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({token, userId})
        }).then(async res => {
        const apiRes = await res.json()
        const {error, message} = apiRes as {message: string; error: string}
           
            if(res.ok){
                console.log(message)
                router.replace("/") }

            if(!res.ok && error) {
                console.log(error)
            }

        })
    }, [])

    
    

    if(!token || !userId)return notFound()

    return (
    <div className='text-3xl opacity-70 text-center p-5 animate-pulse'>
       Please wait... 
       <p>
       We are veryfing your email
       </p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

and this is my component from where the request /api/users/verify is done:

```
import EmailVerificationToken from "@/app/models/emailVerificationToken";
import UserModel from "@/app/models/userModel";
import { EmailVerifyRequest } from "@/app/types"
import { isValidObjectId } from "mongoose";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export const POST =  async (req: Request) => {

   try {
      
      const {token, userId} = await req.json() as EmailVerifyRequest;


      if(!isValidObjectId(userId) || !token) {
       return NextResponse.json(
       {error:'invalid request, userId and token is required'},
       {status: 401}
       )
      }
   
      const verifyToken = await EmailVerificationToken.findOne({user: userId})
   
      if(!verifyToken) {
       return NextResponse.json(
       {error:'invalid token'},
       {status: 401}
       )
      }
   
   
     const isMatched = await verifyToken.compareToken(token)
   
     if(!isMatched) {
       return NextResponse.json(
       {error:'invalid token, token doesnt match'},
       {status: 401}
       )
      }
   
   
      await UserModel.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, {verifyToken:true})
   
      await EmailVerificationToken.findByIdAndDelete(verifyToken._id)
   
      return NextResponse.json({message: 'your email is verified'})
   



   } catch (error) {
      return NextResponse.json({
       error: 'could not verify email, something went wrong'
      }, {status: 500})
   }


  
}
```

hope someone could help me find the syntax error

Comment: So did you checked in the Network tab of the browser what was actually returned by server for this fetch POST request? Most likely it was not JSON returned, but classic html page/content with some error description.

Comment: trying to fix it

Comment: @Pepitos333 Check the response from `/api/users/verify`. Thats not in JSON. Hence your error.

Comment: I've updated my question including the route component, can0t find the syntax error yes hope someone could